# How can I retain CGPDFDictionaryRef?

Tags: objective-c, retain, cgpdfdictionaryref

Any ideas how to "retain" CGPDFDictionaryRef? CFRetain not working, but there must be way to "retain" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDictionary/Reference/reference.html)

> This opaque type is not derived from
>   CFType and therefore there are no
>   functions for retaining and releasing
>   it. CGPDFDictionary objects exist only
>   as constituent parts of a
>   CGPDFDocument object, and they are
>   managed by their container.

Comment: yes, saw that. But i guess i missed key part 'they are managed by their container'

Answer (score 0):

A CGPDFDictionaryRef is just a pointer to a struct. Thus, you can easily retain it when boxed into a NSValue.

Of course the object parent container (CGPDFDocument and CGPDFPage) need to be kept in memory or the pointers within the struct will go invalid.