# How to release a CGPDFArrayRef object in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, cgpdfdocument

I am using the following method fro pdf manipulation

```
CGPDFDictionaryRef pageDictionary = CGPDFPageGetDictionary(pPage);
 CGPDFArrayRef outputArray;
 if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(pageDictionary, "Annots", &outputArray)) {
 }
```

On analyzing using xcode i am getting memory leak for outputArrAY. How can i release outputArray which is a CGPDFArrayRef.

Also how can i release tempStr in the following method in arc :

```
 NSString *tempStr = (__bridge NSString *)CGPDFStringCopyTextString(objectString);
```

Comment: It seems to me you are looking for `CFRelease()` and `__bridge_transfer`.

Comment: But we can't we use CFRelease to CGPDFObjects , right

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4160064/730701)

Comment: Or read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPDFArray/Reference/reference.html).